# Jenkins build fails with error: Error creating releases.jenkins.io

Tags: jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-x

In our CICD pipeline, we have a step of installing a helm chart using the command:
jx step helm install

**our command:**

```
jx step helm install --version= --name=test-release --namespace= --set-file=
```

Appropriate values are provided for all the parameters mentioned in above command

Upon running this command, we are getting the below error:

**Error creating releases.jenkins.io: the server could not find the requested resource**

It appears like system tries the same command multiple times as the same error is shown up multiple times in console and finally it fails with the below error:

**error: failed to register the Team CRD: the server could not find the requested resource**

Can someone help me with this ??

I am bit new to jx so please bear with me.

Thanks and Regards.